# Can I use real probability distributions as labels for tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, softmax

In Tensorflow manual, description for labels is like below:

> labels: Each row labels[i] must be a valid probability distribution.

Then, does it mean labels can be like below, if I have real probability distributions of classes for each input.

```
[[0.1, 0.2, 0.05, 0.007 ... ]
[0.001, 0.2, 0.5, 0.007 ... ]
[0.01, 0.0002, 0.005, 0.7 ... ]]
```

And, is it more efficient than one-hot encoded labels?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word, yes, you can use probabilities as labels.

The documentation for `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` says you can:

> **NOTE:**  While the classes are mutually exclusive, their probabilities
>   need not be.  All that is required is that each row of `labels` is
>   a valid probability distribution.  If they are not, the computation of the
>   gradient will be incorrect.
>
> If using exclusive `labels` (wherein one and only
>   one class is true at a time), see `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`.

Let's have a short example to be sure it works ok:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

labels = np.array([[0.2, 0.3, 0.5], [0.1, 0.7, 0.2]])
logits = np.array([[5.0, 7.0, 8.0], [1.0, 2.0, 4.0]])

sess = tf.Session()
ce = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
     labels=labels, logits=logits).eval(session=sess)
print(ce)  # [ 1.24901222  1.86984602]

# manual check
predictions = np.exp(logits)
predictions = predictions / predictions.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
ce_np = (-labels * np.log(predictions)).sum(axis=1)
print(ce_np)  # [ 1.24901222  1.86984602]
```

And if you have exclusive labels, it is better to use one-hot encoding and `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` rather than `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`and explicit probability representation like `[1.0, 0.0, ...]`. You can have shorter representation that way.